Unknown symbol __stack_chk_guard
I am trying to write GPIO sysfs driver implementation from stratch. When i use final code, it gives error: Unknown symbol __stack_chk_guard
When I trimmed my code to find which line this error occurred in, I first found the following line.of_property_read_string(child, "label", &name);Because the very simple code below also gives the same error.
#include<linux/module.h>
#include <linux/of.h>

/*Module's init entry point */
static int __init helloworld_init(void)
{
    const char *name;
    of_property_read_string(NULL, "label", &name);

   pr_info("Hello world\n");
   return 0;
}

/*Module's cleanup entry point */
static void __exit helloworld_cleanup(void)
{

  pr_info("Good bye world\n");
}

module_init(helloworld_init);
module_exit(helloworld_cleanup);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("asdsa");

How can i fix the error?

Instead of just a terse summation of the error, please provide the full error message with context.
